# Join two cells data - COCATENATE not working properly

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace, formulas, worksheet-function, concatenate

I'm using the following formula to get the data of two cells:

```
=CONCATENATE(C2,"Dia",E2)
```

But it's not working properly. Take a look at the screenshots:

[image]
[image]

It should be returning the Traffic + Date, but it's returning a value that I can't recognize.

So far, without joining both cells data, this is what I've achieved and what I need to achieve:

[image]

Also I'd like to know if there's a way to merge two cells of another spreadsheet using a formula like this: `='90diasnameone'!B16 + ='90diasnametwo'!C116` (I have no idea on how to do that, that's just an approach)

I already know how to display data in the graphic, so basically I'm just asking how to join two cells data into one cell. Something like: `Julia + Maria = Julia and Maria.`

EDIT: I managed to get the result of joining both data, but this is how it's appearing on the graphic:

[image]

As you can see, the date is appearing below the graphic and the data inside the graphic is messed up.

Comment: As questions post on this site should contain only one question, please move the second question to a new post. Reference [ask].

Comment: It's the same thing, just a little deeper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Date is a number. It's the number of days from Jan 1899. It's just formatted to look like yyyy-mm-dd. To get displayed value instead of actual value, use TO_TEXT

```
=CONCATENATE(C2,"Dia", TO_TEXT(E2))
```

Concatenate will work across different sheets.

Comment: Do you know where I can find a list with all the commands?

Comment: Your solution works by the way. I've used `=CONCATENATE('90diaspessoas'!B16," ", TO_TEXT(E2))`, worked like a charm. Can you please update with the code I've just written here as the answer to my second question where I said "=CONCATENATE('90diaspessoas'!B16," ", TO_TEXT(E2))"???

Comment: I got it to work, but now I have another problem, I'll update my question.